# Scrapy Get returned Value from pipeline

Tags: python, django, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I'm trying to get returned value from pipeline. I'm using yield generator to generate item.

And this is my code.

```
def get_or_create(model):
    model_class = type(model)
    created = False

    try:
        obj = model_class.objects.get(product_company=model.product_company, barcode=model.barcode)
    except model_class.DoesNotExist:
        created = True
        obj = model  # DjangoItem created a model for us.
        obj.save()
    return (obj, created)


def update_model(destination, source, commit=True):
    pk = destination.pk
    source_dict = model_to_dict(source)
    for (key, value) in source_dict.items():
        setattr(destination, key, value)
    setattr(destination, 'pk', pk)
    if commit:
        destination.save()
    return destination
class ProductItemPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):

        if isinstance(item, ProductItem):
            item_model = item.instance
            model, created = get_or_create(item_model)
            item['cover_photo'] = item['files'][0]['path']
            if created:
                item.save()
                for image in item['files']:
                    imageItem = ProductImageItem(image=image['path'], product=model)
                    imageItem.save()
                for comment in item['comments']:
                    commentItem = CommentItem(comment=comment.comment, product=model)
                    commentItem.save()
            return model
```

Also this is my spider.

```
 item = ProductItem(name=name, price=price, barcode=barcode, file_urls=objectImages, product_url=response.url,product_company=company, comments = comments)
        product = yield item
        print type(product)
        print "yield product"
```

And product type is returning nonetype

Answer (score 0):

You don't understand python `yield`. You should use `yield` like `return` for return some function result. You can find more information about generators in this [article](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/04/07/improve-your-python-yield-and-generators-explained/)

So your code will look like

```
item = ProductItem(name=name, price=price, barcode=barcode, file_urls=objectImages, product_url=response.url,product_company=company, comments = comments)
self.logger.debug(type(product))
self.logger.debug('yield product')
yield item
```